# Nhibernate interceptors not picking up properties of base class

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm converting from Fluent to Loquacious, and I've run in to an issue where my interceptors are not getting all the fields like I think they should. If I look at the OnSave function

```
public override Boolean OnSave(Object entity, Object id, Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
```

and take a look at the propertyNames the only items in there are the items that were explicitly mapped in the mapping file (in the example this would just be ID, Start, and End).

In my case though I have a base class which isn't mapped at all. Instead it's just contains properties that get filled out by the interceptors. This used to work in Fluent Nhibernate, but now that I've moved to Nhibernate 3.3 I can't get it to work anymore.

My classes/mapping look something like this

```
public class BaseAuditEntity
{
  public virtual int ModifiedByUserID { get; set; }
  public virtual DateTime LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseAuditEntity
{
  public virtual int ID { get; protected internal set; }
  public virtual DateTime Start { get; protected internal set; }
  public virtual DateTime End { get; protected internal set; }
}

public class FooMap: ClassMapping<Foo>
{
  Id(x => x.ID, m => m.column("fooID"));
  Property(x => x.Start, m => m.column("start"));
  Property(x => x.End, m => m.column("end"));
}
```

Any ideas of how to get this work? I don't want to have to map this every class, and I didn't think I needed to map the BaseAuditEntity, at least with Fluent it wasn't needed.

Comment: did you use automapping with FNH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make a base mapping class

```
public class BaseAuditEntityMapping<T> : ClassMapping<T> where T: BaseAuditEntity
{
    ManyToOne(x => x.ModifiedByUser);
    Property(x => x.LastModifiedTime);
}

public class FooMap: BaseAuditEntityMapping<Foo>
```

Comment: This worked although it isn't exactly what I wanted, I was hoping not to have the change all the mappings to point to BaseAuditEntityMapping, but at this this works. Thanks.

Comment: FNH will not map them on their own except you use automapping. you could use mapping by code's equivalent of automapping to get the same effect